# What is the difference between Hashing vectorizer and Count vectorizer, when each to be used?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I am trying with various SVM variants in scikit-learn along with CountVectorizer and HashingVectorizer. They use fit or fit_transform in different examples, confusing me which to be used when.

Any clarification would be much honored.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They serve a similar purpose. The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html) provides some pro's and con's for the `HashingVectorizer` :

> This strategy has several advantages:
>
> - it is very low memory scalable to large datasets as there is no need to store a vocabulary dictionary in memory
> - it is fast to pickle and un-pickle as it holds no state besides the constructor parameters
> - it can be used in a streaming (partial fit) or parallel pipeline as there is no state computed during fit.
>
> There are also a couple of cons (vs using a CountVectorizer with an
>   in-memory vocabulary):
>
> - there is no way to compute the inverse transform (from feature indices to string feature names) which can be a problem when trying to
>     introspect which features are most important to a model.
> - there can be collisions: distinct tokens can be mapped to the same feature index. However in practice this is rarely an issue if
>     n_features is large enough (e.g. 2 ** 18 for text classification
>     problems).
> - no IDF weighting as this would render the transformer stateful.